# Polymer <polymer-element name="core-spa" extends="core-scaffold"> Wish List Item

Tags: user-interface, mobile, responsive-design, polymer, single-page-application

I am working on creating a SPA (Single Page Application) in Polymer that is based on the Core Scaffold. What is missing is URL Routing that keeps the current view and some data in a pretty URL that can be shared and gives the user a clear preview of the page based on the URL.

The best Router I have found is https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router

The main navigation will be the current "Hamburger" menu (with submenus) at the top left which changes the content of the main area and a "More or Settings" menu at the top right which pops up modal dialog boxes with things like login, settings, preferences etc.

A fast splash page followed by "Lazy Loading" is also required.

And a "Full Screen" button that hides all the clutter and give the mobile use maximum workspace.

Gluing this all together the "Polymer Way" is still confusing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an example linked to from http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#spa which uses `<flatiron-director>` for routing. Implementing "lazy-loading" boils down to how you populate the DOM inside the `<core-pages>`.

Comment: Yes, I have read all the existing documentation and tested the demos. I am looking for more. Always more ;)

Comment: The question is more about gluing together all the various parts in a best practices "Polymer Way". I would invite someone smarter than me to start a GIT project for core-spa.